# Time complexity of the program using recurrence relation

Tags: algorithm, math, recursion, time-complexity

This program calculate fibonacci numbers. I want to find out its time complexity using recurrence relation.

```
Fib(n)
if n<=1
  return n
else
  x= Fib(n-1)
  y= Fib(n-2)
  return x+y
```

The recurrence equation for this program is 
  **T(n)=T(n-1)+T(n-2)+c**

I tried to expend it , but couldn't find the solution.

```
 =2T(n-1)+T(n-3)+c+c
 =3T(n-3)+2T(n-4)+c+c+3c
 =5T(n-4)+3T(n-3)+c+c+3c+5c
 -------------------------
 -------------------------
 -------------------------
```

Comment: What is this term 'complexity'? This is not a mathematical notion that I am aware of...

Comment: @Killercam http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity

Comment: Thinking about it, I am not sure what I would call this. Perhaps I have just forgotten the use of the term 'complexity'. Anyway, it will be order n (or O(n)).

Comment: It won't be linear as written. As stated it will be O(Fib(n)), which is exponential. You need to memoize the previous return values to make it linear. Simply put, when you compute x, you need to take y into account because it's part of x. If you don't, you're doing too much work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to think about how many calls you make to your function.
Each call makes 2, so it makes a binary tree:

n

(n-1)--------------(n-2)

(n-2)--(n-3)------(n-3)---(n-4)

and so on.

Consider the level of the tree when you first reach 1 and ignore everything below.
This happens on level n/2 (since the lowest number of each level is the rightmost and it always decreases by 2).
It's clear that the nodes on each level up to n/2 are always twice as many as on the previous level.

Thus the total number of nodes is 1 + 2 + 2^2 + ... + 2^(n/2) = 2^(n/2+1) - 1 = O(2^(n/2))

This means that the time complexity is at least exponential.

You can probably compute it even more accurately, but for all practical purposes this should be enough to avoid this implementation.

Comment: but is it possible to prove that this program has exponential time complexity using recurrence equations ?

Answer (score 1):

The given recurrence relation is,

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) + c   ------ 1
T(n-1)= T(n-2) + T(n-3) + c ------ 2

1-2 -> T(n) = 2T(n-1) - T(n-3) ----- 3
T(n) - 2T(n-1) + T(n-3) = 0 ----- 4
```

The characteristic equation of 4 is **x<sup>3</sup> - 2x<sup>2</sup> + 1 = 0   ----   5**

Solve equation 5,

The solutions are `x = 1`, `x = (1 + √5)/2` and `x = (1 −√5)/2`

There for the general solution is,
**T<sub>n</sub> = a((1 + √5)/2)<sup>n</sup> + b((1 - √5)/2)<sup>n</sup> + c . 1<sup>n</sup>**

There for **T<sub>n</sub> = a((1 + √5)/2)<sup>n</sup> + b((1 - √5)/2)<sup>n</sup> + c**

Let us assume **T(0) = 0**, from equation 1 we get **T(1) = c** and **T(2) = 2c**

There for,
 **T(0) = a + b + c = 0 ---- 6**

**T(1) = a((1 + √5)/2) + b((1 - √5)/2) + c = c**

There for **a((1 + √5)/2) + b((1 - √5)/2) = 0  ----- 7**

**T(2) = a((1 + √5)/2)<sup>2</sup> + b((1 - √5)/2)<sup>2</sup> + c = 2c**

There for **a((1 + √5)/2)<sup>2</sup> + b((1 - √5)/2)<sup>2</sup> = c ---- 8**

solve 6, 7 and 8, to get the values of a, b and c.

The general solution is,

**T<sub>n</sub> = a((1 + √5)/2)<sup>n</sup> + b((1 - √5)/2)<sup>n</sup> + c**

since **(1 + √5)/2 < 2**,

**T(n) = O(2<sup>n</sup>).**

Answer (score 0):

The thing to note about *your* recurrence relation is that it's ***the same as the Fibonacci recurrence itself***. This means that you're doing `c` units of work times whatever Fibonacci number you're calculating. You can see it yourself from the first few steps that you computed. The `c`'s start growing like the Fibonacci numbers.

Basically your recurrence comes down to O(Fib(n)).  Fibonacci numbers are exponential in `n`, so you're going to do exponential work.

A better way to do this is to remember one of the numbers. Like this:

```
Fib(n):
    if n <= 2:
        return 1,0
    else:
        x,y = Fib(n-1)
        return x+y,x
```

So when you call `Fib(n)`, you're getting two values, Fib(n) and Fib(n-1). That extra `x` that you return "remembers" Fib(n-2) so you don't have to compute it twice. *This* recurrence comes down to `T(n) = T(n-1) + c`, which is O(n).

Once you have that, you can reduce this to a nice little for loop:

```
x = 1, y = 0
for i from 3 to n:
    x,y = x+y,x
```